# App types in iPhone Sdk

Tags: iphone

can anybody explain in terms of utility whats the difference between

1.View Based App
2. Windows Based App
3. Navigation Based App

Thanks!

Taimur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most give a skeleton for that type of application. Try them.

As far as I know there is nothing set in stone with any of these, so you can convert to what ever you want. Personally I just start with the Window-based app as it has the least crap included.